# Laravel Factory Can't Save Relation

Tags: laravel, laravel-seeding

I use Laravel 5.6, and I have a problem with my seeder.

I use this :

```
factory(\App\Models\Merchant::class)->create([
    'email' => 'admin@domain.com',
])->each(function ($m) {
    $m->stores()->save(factory(\App\Models\Store::class)->create()
        ->each(function ($s) {
            $s->products()->save(factory(\App\Models\Product::class, 10)->create());
        })
    );
});
```

All are *hasMany* relations.

Doing this, I have this error :

> General error: 1364 Field 'merchant_id' doesn't have a default value
>   (SQL: insert into `stores` ....)

It's like my first *$stores->save( ... )* doesn't use the merchant created.

In my DB, I have one merchant created.

If I use `->make()` instead of `->create()`, it works for the Store, but I can't save products because it's not persisted...

Is it possible to use multiple save in factories like this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code may need a little refactoring as you may be chaining creation of models incorrectly:

```
factory(\App\Models\Merchant::class, 2)->create([
    'email' => 'admin@domain.com',
])->each(function ($m) {
    $store = factory(\App\Models\Store::class)->create(['merchent_id' => $m->id]);
    factory(\App\Models\Product::class, 10)->create(['store_id' -> $store->id]);
    );
});
```

**Note**: In order to use the `->each()` method, you need to have a `collection` instance. I do not think creating only **one** merchant will return a collection. In the example, we create 2 `merchents`.

Comment: Yes ok, I thought ther was a cleaner way to do this, but I gave up.. this one works thanks